# How to write filter condition for specific object key?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have an object:

```
const list = {
  apples: '2',
  grapes: '1',
  almonds: 'allergic',
  bags: '',
}
```

What I want to is if `list.bags === ''` exclude it from object, so that final result will be:

```
const list = {
  apples: '2',
  grapes: '1',
  almonds: 'allergic',
}
```

I tried filtering it out, but it always removes `bags`

```
const newList = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(list).filter(
            ([key, v]) => key !== 'bags' && v !== '',
        ),
);
```

How can I write this type of condition for `filter`?

Comment: Do you need to clone the object? If not you can just use `delete list.bags`.

Comment: The fix is just `key !== 'bags' || v !== ''` but I'd go with @FelixKling and say it's way easier as `if (list.bags === "") delete list.bags;`

Comment: @Felix Kling I need to have `newList` object without `bags` and original `list` with all keys

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove a single property, I'd use `Object.assign` (or spread properties) to clone the object and just `delete` that property if necessary:

```
const newList = {...list};
if (newList.bags === '') {
  delete newList.bags;
}
```